# Session expires very often in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I am working on developing MVC5 application. 
I have used session to store user data.

Below is the code which i am using to store session data

```
if (Session["UserData"] == null)
{
   Session["UserData"] = _objLoginSession;
}
```

I have also increased Session Timeout in web.config, which is as below

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60">
</sessionState>
```

My authentication mode is also none

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

But when i run my application, it expires with in 1 - 2 minutes only.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 2):

One reason why ASP.NET session might *expire* that comes to mind is this: session data is kept in memory since you specified InProc mode, so if you recompile your application in Visual Studio or for some reason your application is restarted you will lose session data. And there are plenty of reasons why your application might get restarted by the web server. Things like changing web.config or some files in the `bin` folder or your computer starts running on low memory.

All those reasons indicate that you should absolutely never (except while developing) keep session data in memory (InProc).

Comment: What is the suggested way?

Comment: Never use `InProc` in production and while developing keep in mind that if you recompile your application you will lose data. You can also switch to some persistent session store in development if you want to preserve session data through application restarts. Or even better: don't use any sessions at all. Design your application so that it is completely stateless. I've always considered ASP.NET sessions as an unnecessary evil.

Comment: While Darin has a point with stateless web apps, it doesn't actually answer your question - why your session expires. There are websites working for many years with InProc session without such problems. If your session really expires then it is easy to find out - put a breakpoint in Session_End method in your Global.asax file. And besides the problems of recompiling the app or changing the web.config which are quite easy to spot, try also with cookie less sessions (check the cookieless attribute of <sessionState>) to see if the problem is related to your browser. Hope it helps.